# Proguard Maven Plugin Doesn't Use The Specified Proguard Version

Tags: java, maven, proguard, maven-plugin, obfuscation

The Proguard Maven Plugin is not using the specified proguard version and thus I am getting the following error:
`(Can't process class [com/sun/javafx/charts/ChartLayoutAnimator.class] (Unsupported class version number [54.0] (maximum 52.0, Java 1.8)))`

Let me know if you have any idea how I can force the plugin to use a more recent version.

***pom.xml***

```
     <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.14</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</injar> <!-- make sure to obfuscate the jar with dependencies -->
                            <proguardVersion>6.2.2</proguardVersion>
                            <options>
                                <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                                <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                                <option>-dontshrink</option>
                                <option>-dontnote</option>
                                <option>-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod</option>
                                <option>-flattenpackagehierarchy ''</option>
                                <option>-dontwarn</option> <!-- added option to ignore com.sun missing classes -->
                                <option>-keepattributes Signature</option>
<!--
                                <option>-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main, obfuscationexample.ObfuscationExample { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }</option>
-->
                                <option>-keep public class com.myproject.** { *; }</option>
                                <option>-keepclassmembernames class * { @javafx.fxml.FXML *; }</option>
                            </options>
                            <libs>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                                <lib>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</lib>

                            </libs>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

   <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you have to close the executions element before opening the configuration.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.14</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <injar>${project.build.finalName}-jar-with-dependencies.jar
                </injar> <!-- make sure to obfuscate the jar with dependencies -->
                <proguardVersion>6.2.2</proguardVersion>
                <options>
                    <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                    <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                    <option>-dontshrink</option>
                    <option>-dontnote</option>
                    <option>-keepattributes
                        Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
                    </option>
                    <option>-flattenpackagehierarchy ''</option>
                    <option>-dontwarn</option> <!-- added option to ignore com.sun missing classes -->
                    <option>-keepattributes Signature</option>
                    <!--
                                                    <option>-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main, obfuscationexample.ObfuscationExample { public static void main(java.lang.String[]); }</option>
                    -->
                    <option>-keep public class com.myproject.** { *; }</option>
                    <option>-keepclassmembernames class * { @javafx.fxml.FXML *; }</option>
                </options>

            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>6.2.2</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: are there any other requirements to consider to be able to run this correctly? Nothing happens when i use the plugin. no file is generated.

Comment: @chitgoks Many things might have gone wrong, I would recommend debugging it by adding the "-X' flag after the mvn command to run the plugin. It will print out verbose logs.